# PHP: Adding two images in one line

Tags: php, image, upload

I have a php script that adds an image to a directory.

It looks like:

```
//SET DESINATION FOLDER
        $path = ABSPATH."image/display/".$new_image_name;
        $pathlarge = ABSPATH."image/display/full_size/".$new_image_name;

        if($product_img !=none)
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img']['tmp_name'], $path))
            {
```

I am trying to add a 2nd image. Would I do this something like:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img']['tmp_name'], $path) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_img']['tmp_name'], $pathlarge))
```

It doesnt seem to work for me. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two `&& &&` ? Isn't that it?

Comment: Sorry, that occurred when I copied the code up there - am editing now